# C++ Undefined Reference When Compiling .h and .cpp in Subfolders

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, subdirectory

Long story short I want to put my .h and .cpp files in subfolders (include and src respectively) and reference them in my main.cpp file but I am receiving an error of:

`` main.cpp:(.text+0x47): undefined reference to `Kmer::Kmer()'. ``

when compiling using:

`g++ -I /path/to/MyFolder/include main.cpp`.

My files are structured like below:

- MyFolder

  - main.cpp
  - include

    - Kmer.h
  - src

    - Kmer.cpp

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Kmer.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Kmer k;
    return 0;
};
```

```
//Kmer.h
#pragma once

class Kmer{
  public:
    Kmer();
  protected:
  private:
};
```

```
//Kmer.cpp
#include "Kmer.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Kmer::Kmer(){
  // code here
  cout << "Kmer created" << endl;
}
```

I appreciate the help!

Comment: `#include "Kmer.h"` maybe you want `#include "include/Kmer.h"`

Comment: Thanks for the response! I did that just to test it out and I received the same error message. I also prefer using the -I command in g++ instead of using relative paths in my code if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not compiling Khmer.cpp. You need to add it to your g++ compile line

```
g++ -o <YOUR APPLICATION NAME> -I /path/to/MyFolder/include main.cpp src/Khmer.cpp
```

Comment: Thanks! Small edit was adding src/Kmer.cpp to the g++ command worked! Do I need to add every .cpp file to that command for compiling if I use this method?

```g++ -o <YOUR APPLICATION NAME> -I /path/to/MyFolder/include main.cpp src/Kmer.cpp```

Comment: @DouglasFur If you have many `.cpp` files, you usually build each one separately and link the object files together as a final step. Makefiles or IDE project files usually helps with this so it doesn't become too much work.

Comment: I can second taking the time to learn about makefiles if you intend on creating large projects with many source files.

Comment: Thanks! I will for sure look into Makefiles. I am starting to convert my python libraries to C++. Do any of you have suggestions as to the best C++ documentation/resources?

Comment: Bruh, I've been tinkering for 30 minutes before I got it work with this solution.